# Set position for each flag in highstock

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to change the position of each flag in a chart and I'm using highstock.
I add each flag like this:

```
 {
        x: time,
        shape: 'url(images/indicators/down_fractal.png)',
        y:value,
        title: ' ',
        text: 'Fractal: ' + value
    };
```

And there is my serie config:

```
seriesConf : {
            id: this.uniqueID,
            name: this.toString(),
            data: this.indicatorData,
            type: 'flags',
            onSeries: this.options.onSeriesID, //Series ID on which this flags will be rendered
            height: 10,
            width: 10,
            //y: 100,
            //turboThreshold: 0
        }
```

The y value is suppose to set the position of flag but its not working?is it even possible to define each flag position?
In this [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/ujgLzkq9/) you change the y value and nothing happens.
The main i idea is to create a chart like this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the question. Can you please share if you were able to accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Flag series is rendered directly above the series, there is no `y` option for point (see [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#series<flags>.data)).

I think you want to use simple scatter series with markers, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/ujgLzkq9/1/

Or use two flag series (one above, and second one below the line), using [`series.y`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#series<flags>.y) option.

Comment: Thank.I think the scatter is the answer